# Using Perl, how can I find and remove files with a specific suffix?

Tags: perl

I need to write a function in Perl that removes all files with the `.rc` suffix under a certain location and its subdirectories (lets call it targetroot).

I am working in NT env, so I can't use system commands like `find`, or `rm`.
I have tired to do it with unlink and find options but didn't manage.

What I have tried is:

```perl
print "\n<<<    Removing .rc files from $targetRoot\\20140929_231622    >>>\n";
my $dir = "$targetRoot\\20140929_231622";
find(\&wanted, $dir);
sub wanted 
{ 
  unlink glob "*.rc";
}
```

Can someone show me how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You're pretty close. `File::Find` is the tool for the job here. Try putting your `wanted()` as:

```
sub  wanted {
    # $_ set to filename; $File::Find::name set to full path.
    if ( -f and m/\.rc\z/i ) {
        print "Removing $File::Find::name\n"; 
        unlink ( $File::Find::name );
    }
}
```

Try it first without the unlink of course, to verify you get the right targets. Bear in mind `File::Find` will recurse down the directory structure by default.

Comment: you mean run it like that?  sub RemoveRC
{
 print "\n<<< Removing .rc files from $targetRoot\\20140929_231622 >>>\n";
 my $dir = "$targetRoot\\20140929_231622";
  find(\&wanted, $dir);
sub wanted {
     # $_ set to filename; $File::Find::name set to full path.
    if ( m/\.rc\Z/ ) {
        print "Removing $File::Find::name\n"; 
        #unlink ( $File::Find::name );
    }
}

}

Comment: Er. I think so. Good practice is always to comment out the 'dangerous bits' when running someone elses code. I'm pretty sure that'll work, but I'm just some guy on the internet. Comment out the `unlink` see what it prints as 'would remove'. Then put it back in if you're happy.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: Windows filenames may not contain control characters, so `\z`, `\Z` and `$` are all fine.

Comment: @Sobrique: You should also check that the node is a file and not a directory, and it would be nice to check for `*.RC` as well as `*.rc`. Like this `if ( -f and /\.rc$/ ) { ... }`

Comment: Updated based on comments.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the `wanted` subroutine:

```
sub wanted { /\.rc$/ && ( unlink $File::Find::name or die "Unable to delete $_: $!" ) }
```

---

From the [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) documentation

> **The `wanted` function**
>
> The `wanted()` function does whatever verifications you want on each
>   file and directory. Note that despite its name, the `wanted()`
>   function is a generic callback function, and does not tell
>   `File::Find` if a file is "wanted" or not. In fact, its return value
>   is ignored.
>
> The wanted function takes no arguments but rather does its work
>   through a collection of variables.
>
> ```
> `$File::Find::dir` is the current directory name,
>
> `$_` is the current filename within that directory
>
> `$File::Find::name` is the complete pathname to the file.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

[Path::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class) makes things a little nicer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Class;

run(@ARGV ? \@ARGV : ['.']);

sub run {
    my $argv = shift;
    my $dir = dir(shift @$argv)->resolve; # will croak if path does not exist
    $dir->recurse(callback => \&rm_if_rcfile);
    return;
}

sub rm_if_rcfile {
    my $entity = shift;
    return if $entity->is_dir;
    return unless $entity =~ / [.] rc \z/ix;
    print "$entity\n";
    return; # remove this line to actually delete
    unless ($entity->remove) {
        warn "'$entity' failed: $!\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use File::Find;

my $dir = "targetRoot\\20140929_231622";

find(
    sub {
        unlink if -f && /\.rc$/i;
    },
    $dir
);
```

Or using [`File::Find::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use File::Find::Rule;

my $dir = "targetRoot\\20140929_231622";

for ( File::Find::Rule->file()->name('*.rc')->in($dir) ) {
    unlink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this block of code :

```
my $dir = "$targetRoot\\20140929_231622";
#subroutine call
wanted($dir);

#subroutine declaration
sub wanted 
{ 
    my $result = $_[0];

  my @p = grep {-f} glob("$result\\*.rc");
  foreach my $file (@p)
   {
     print "Removing files $file from the directory $dir" . unlink($file) . "\n";

    }
}
```

Comment: But I think there's something just a little bit dirty about a recursive traversal combined with a wildcarded `glob`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from defining `$targetRoot`, all you need to do is change your `wanted` sub.

`File::Find` calls `wanted` for *every* node (file or directory) that it finds beneath the root directory that you specify. It will have put the basename (the bare file name without path information) into `$_`, and done a `chdir` to the directory that contains it.

Since the default action of `unlink` -- if you don't pass a parameter -- is to delete the file specified by `$_`, all you need to do is check that it is a file and ends with `.rc`.

This version of `wanted` will do that for you.

```
sub wanted { 
  unlink if -f and /\.rc\z/i;
}
```

And that subroutine is so short that you may as well use an anonymous subroutine in the call to `find`. Here's the complete version, which also warns if the delete fails on any file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my $targetRoot = 'C:\path\to\root';
my $dir        = "$targetRoot\\20140929_231622";

print qq{\n<<<    Removing .rc files from "$dir"    >>>\n};

find(sub {
  -f and /\.rc\z/i and unlink or warn qq{Unable to delete "$File::Find::name"\n};
}, $dir);
```

Comment: @Zaid: Thanks. That'll teach me to type code straight into SO!